# Error: spawnSync PATH/target/node/node ENOENTNGCC failed, see above

Tags: angular, typescript, maven, npm, package.json

I am trying to start my angular project using ./mvnw, however when the build is running
`ng build --configuration development`

then the following error is thrown:

```
 Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
[INFO] /home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:139
[INFO]             throw new Error(errorMessage + `NGCC failed${errorMessage ? ', see above' : ''}.`);
[INFO]                   ^
[INFO] 
[INFO] Error: spawnSync /home/user/Desktop/project/target/node/node ENOENTNGCC failed, see above.
[INFO]     at NgccProcessor.process (/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:139:19)
[INFO]     at /home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:143:27
[INFO]     at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
[INFO]     at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
[INFO]     at Compiler.newCompilation (/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1054:30)
[INFO]     at /home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1099:29
[INFO]     at eval (eval at create (/home/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

However when i run the same command locally without the maven wrapper then the `ng build` succeeds.

My dependencies in package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/localize": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "13.1.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "11.0.0",
    "@ngqp/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
    "ajv": "^8.10.0",
    "angular-tag-cloud-module": "^13.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.1",
    "dayjs": "1.10.7",
    "emoji-toolkit": "^6.6.0",
    "katex": "^0.15.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.1.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "10.0.1",
    "ngx-markdown": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "9.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "4.2.1",
    "ts-color-class": "^0.10.1",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "13.0.0",
    "@angular-builders/jest": "13.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.1.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.1.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "13.1.3",
    "@types/chai": "4.2.14",
    "@types/chai-string": "1.4.2",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/mocha": "8.2.0",
    "@types/node": "16.11.21",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "4.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.10.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.27.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "chai-string": "1.5.0",
    "concurrently": "7.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "10.2.1",
    "eslint": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "3.1.1",
    "folder-hash": "4.0.1",
    "generator-jhipster": "7.6.0",
    "husky": "7.0.4",
    "jest": "27.4.7",
    "jest-date-mock": "1.0.8",
    "jest-junit": "13.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "11.0.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "12.2.2",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1",
    "mocha": "8.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "1.6.1",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "2.2.15",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.3",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "typescript": "4.5.4",
    "wait-on": "6.0.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.8",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.5.0",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.15.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.1"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "target/test-results/jest",
    "reportFile": "TESTS-results-sonar.xml"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "webpack": "5.66.0"
  }
```

I have tryied to set ivy compiler options to false or true and it did not work as well. Then I tried to delete or update thrid party packages but still I did not succeed in identifying the package which can not be processed. Also of course I always deleted the package-lock.json and nodemodules before rebuilding with the ./mvnw command.

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours I was finally able to solve this error.
The problem was that one third party library could not handle the new angular compiler (ivy or so) and my local `ng build` command used an old compiler version which was not using ivy. However, to disable ivy as recommended in many other posts did not work.
To solve the issue, I had to delete all third party packages in my package.json and then one by one add (and delete package-lock.json, node_moules and target just to be sure) this package again and then check if this `Error: spawnSync /home/user/Desktop/project/target/node/node ENOENTNGCC failed, see above.` appeared or not.
In my case `"katex": "^0.15.2"` was the problem. Removing it solved my problems.